# Why when using texttospeech in visual studio in android project i'm getting errors?

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin, xamarin-studio

Couldn't find complete solution code.
I can't figure out how to use the text to speech inonlistner event.
When I type: Android.Speech.Tts I don't have after the Tts.TextToSpeech but in all example in the internet I see TextToSpeech after the Tts.

I downloaded all packages in the android sdk manager.
And I can't figure out how to implement the txt to speech code at all in the main activity.

I saw in some examples this instance of TextTospeech with (this, this) but i'm getting errors on it.

I tried it now on visual studio: New project > android > Blank app (android) 
I tried it on android studio and also in xamarin studio. In all cases I can't figure out how to implement the texttospeech.

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Speech.Tts;


namespace App1
{
    [Activity(Label = "App1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;


        TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

            button.Click += delegate {
                button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++);
            };
        }


    }
}
```

The error is on the line:

```
TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
```

> Error 4   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'App1.MainActivity' to 'Android.Speech.Tts.TextToSpeech.IOnInitListener'

And

> Error 1   Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context

And

> Error 3   The best overloaded method match for 'Android.Speech.Tts.TextToSpeech.TextToSpeech(Android.Content.Context, Android.Speech.Tts.TextToSpeech.IOnInitListener)' has some invalid arguments

What I tried so far:

In visual studio when I created a new android solution I got this code in the MainActivity.cs file and I added the TextToSpeech variable and instance:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Speech.Tts;

namespace App3
{
    [Activity(Label = "App3", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;
        private EditText write;
        TextToSpeech ttobj = getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
   @Override
   public void onInit(int status) {
   }
}
);

       // TextToSpeech listener = new TextToSpeech(Context.te);




        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it



            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

            button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };
        }
    }
}
```

Adding just TextToSpeech ttobj was fine but once I tried to instance it I got errors:  `getApplicationContext()` this is not exist then `OnInitListener()` also not exist. `@Override` could not be found are you missing....etc and on public:

> Error 3   Member modifier 'public' must precede the member type and name

So I guess i'm all wrong and messed it all up.

Comment: Here in this document it says that android.speech.tts.texttospeech is in mono.android.dll I added this dll as reference to my project and still I don't have TextToSpeech after the Tts: http://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Speech.Tts.TextToSpeech.Speak(System.String,Android.Speech.Tts.QueueMode,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary%7BSystem.String,System.String%7D)/

Comment: Have you read the Xamarin docs on [TextToSpeech](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/speech/) including the **complete, working source code for an app** that it includes?  You keep posting the same questions over and over.

Comment: also **this** is basic C# - it refers to the instance of the class that is running, so is only available within an instance method, not in the class body.  Move the code that instantiates TextToSpeech into the constructor, and also make your class inherit from  TextToSpeech.IOnInitListener